# Headlines right-padding doesn't work as expected

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created a website according to the following design:

[image]

As you can see, the main heading has this light blue background behind it. 
So far, I have used 'padding-right' in order to achieve this wide background affect, and used the background attribute on the class but it got messed up and only the text is covered with a light blue background. There isn't that wide-background effect. I tried switching the class to the ID of each headline (#title1, #title2 and etc...), but then the entire line got filled up with a light blue background and I need it way shorter.

Here's the HTML:

```
<p dir="rtl"><span class="bluetitle"><span style="background-color:#dff2f6">headline<font color="#dff2f6">.</font></span></span><span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.938em; font-weight: 600;"></span></p>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1920px) {
#title1{
padding-right: 27.5% !important;
background-color: #dff2f;
}
}
@media (min-width: 1920px) {
#title2{
padding-right: 21.3% !important;}
}
@media (min-width: 1920px) {
#title3{
padding-right: 37.2% !important;}
}
@media (min-width: 1920px) {
#title4{
padding-right: 23.75% !important;}
}
@media (min-width: 1920px) {
#title5{
padding-right: 26.3% !important;
}}
```

Now I can't get the light blue background to look exactly like the design. Previously, I gave all the spans the ID of #bluetitle, and gave them the same margin-right unit, but they weren't aligned according to the design. I also tried aligning all the titles to the left and then I didn't get this long line of blue background, but it seems like the background wasn't the same height like here:

[image]

If you wanna inspect the website, you can find it here: [www.mayabarber.co.il](http://www.mayabarber.co.il)

Can anyone please tell me how I can achieve the same effect from the design?

Thanks!

Comment: Two issues: First, IDs must be unique. You can't have multiple with the same value. Then, all those `!important` modifiers are red flags for bad CSS design. Unless you're overriding a third-party widget, they shouldn't be needed. That said, I can't see the problem on your site. Please provide a standalone demo here or at https://jsfiddle.net, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're trying to do it is a bit clumsy. I created a more simple and flexible solution for you just so you get the point of how it should work:

First, I placed the headline near the paragraph as a sibling.
Next, I added `:before` pseudo to the headline whos responsible for the continuing background. This way you don't need to worry about the size of the headline. The background will adapt itself to the headline:

```css
body{
  direction: rtl
}
h2 {
  background-color: #dff2f6;
  color: #001a71;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  animation: do-the-weird-padding-thingy ease infinite 5s;
}

h2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #dff2f6;
  width: 100vw;
  left: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 90%;
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  animation: show-how-amazingly-flexible-cool-thingy-it-is ease infinite 10s
}

@keyframes show-how-amazingly-flexible-cool-thingy-it-is {
  0% { width: 600px }
  50% { width: 400px }
  100% { width: 600px }
}

@keyframes do-the-weird-padding-thingy {
  0% { padding: 0 }
  50% { padding: 30px 0 }
  100% { padding: 0 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h2>This is just a headline</h3>
  </div>
  
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to assist me. However, I don't want the entire line to be filled with a light blue background. I want it to be just like in the screenshot I have added from the design itself. The background should spread to the right of the text, and cover the text only. The width property is making the entire line be filled with a light blue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're seeing. the line is not entirely background-colored. I have updated my answer so you can see it spread to the right of the text instead to the left.

Comment: The idea of my solution is to make the headline relative, and then add `:before` and let it 100 viewport width, and place it absolutely on the right of headline.

Comment: Should I drop the media queries? I was trying to make it responsive on all displays.

Comment: Short answer - Yes. Long answer - You can see I added: "top: 0; bottom: 0" to the :before. Meaning - it will always have the height of the current headline.

Comment: Okay, thanks. And two last question. since I'm working with a live builder (Elementor Pro) I have to ditch the container part and stick to the headline only. 
1. Can I use your code only to design the big headlines and not the entire paragraph? 
2. Previously, I had this issue of running the website on a 1920px width 15'' laptop and 25'' and these headlines looked different. That's why I was advised to use percentage instead of px unit. It wasn't a top-bottom issue, but just right-left properties. So your last answer applies to that too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173572/discussion-between-rozi-buber-and-eliya-cohen).